# calibrating Google map

Tags: javascript, tasker

Android 11 and 12.
Google map compass calibration screen -- intent ?. Here is the Google map [AndroidManifest file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E1cfgLcnyHUMLOmcotRzsLbTWfeaWaYu/view?usp=share_link)

I live in a rugged area with a lot of trees and mountains that screw up my google map compass. And I have to re-calibrate the phone compass to get it back on track. The problem is that there is no button to start this, except make a figure eight in the air, and that should calibrate the compass. This works poorly and I can struggle with this for 10 minutes before the calibration appears, see picture. https://ibb.co/k0VbHGz

I see on the internet that there are some who have a link in google maps to click to bring up this option, and also in android settings. but I have none of this options.

But since the feature is in the Google map app, shouldn't it be possible to link to that feature directly from Tasker ??? and create a link or a button via a scene. So I can start that function manually?.How do I go about accomplishing this?. explain so that I, as a beginner, understand :)

Edit ....
I find this by using LogCat  - Image:  https://ibb.co/0tFTJ44

```
View
requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.LinearLayout{30e43fa V.E...... ......I. 0,285-1080,429 #7f0b0196 app:id/compass_container} during layout: running second layout pass
```

How do I convert or create a link from this that I can use in Tasker?.